# 3D perspective mode using xy package

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic, commutative-diagrams, xymatrix, diagxy

Starting from this code where I have used `xy` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}


\begin{document}
\xymatrix@!0{
& \alpha \ar@{-}[rr]\ar@{-}'[d][dd]
& & \beta D \ar@{-}[dd]
\\
\gamma \ar@{-}[ur]\ar@{-}[rr]\ar@{-}[dd]
& & \delta A \ar@{-}[ur]\ar@{-}[dd]
\\
& ax \ar@{-}'[r][rr]
& & bx\xi\mu
\\
\Gamma_r(f(x,y)) \ar@{-}[rr]\ar@{-}[ur]
& & \lambda P \ar@{-}[ur]
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

looking this image taken in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559643/how-to-make-this-3d-diagram-with-tikz),

[image]

the labels seem to be rotated, put in a frontal perspective. Is it possible to do this with the `xy` package instead of `tikz-cd`?

Comment: please see the  [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119801/89320) of [David Carliste](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) to [Rotating labels in xypic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119796/rotating-labels-in-xypic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Second approach

With the extension *Rotate and Scale extension* by Ross Moore you can also achieve a similar output. Therefore, load the option `\xyoption{rotate}` and add the argument `[@!<number>]` . For further details, see p. 29 of [Reference manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/xypic/xyrefer.pdf)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\xyoption{rotate}


\begin{document}
    \def\angle{50}
    \xymatrix@!0{
        & *+[@!\angle]{\alpha} \ar@{-}[rr]\ar@{-}'[d][dd]
        & & *+[@!\angle]{\beta D} \ar@{-}[dd]
        \\
        \gamma \ar@{-}[ur]\ar@{-}[rr]\ar@{-}[dd]
        & & \delta A \ar@{-}[ur]\ar@{-}[dd]
        \\
        & *+=[@!\angle]{ax} \ar@{-}'[r][rr]
        & & *+=[@!\angle]{bx\xi\mu}
        \\
        \Gamma_r(f(x,y)) \ar@{-}[rr]\ar@{-}[ur]
        & & \lambda P \ar@{-}[ur]
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

### First approach

The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119801/89320) of [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) to [Rotating labels in xypic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119796/rotating-labels-in-xypic) shows you a possible solution, that is, using for example the `\rotatebox` command of the `graphicx` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}


\begin{document}
\def\angle{50}
\xymatrix@!0{
& \rotatebox[origin=c]{\angle}{$\alpha$} \ar@{-}[rr]\ar@{-}'[d][dd]
& & \rotatebox[origin=c]{\angle}{$\beta D$} \ar@{-}[dd]
\\
\gamma \ar@{-}[ur]\ar@{-}[rr]\ar@{-}[dd]
& & \delta A \ar@{-}[ur]\ar@{-}[dd]
\\
& \rotatebox[origin=c]{\angle}{ax} \ar@{-}'[r][rr]
& & \rotatebox[origin=c]{\angle}{$bx\xi\mu$}
\\
\Gamma_r(f(x,y)) \ar@{-}[rr]\ar@{-}[ur]
& & \lambda P \ar@{-}[ur]
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you nako but the label not are parallel with the line. See the pink rectangle of the 2nd image. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @Sebastiano you can add the option `[origin=c]`, see the edit, please

Comment: I'll probably change the initial MWE and build the basis of the second design. I'm not so sure this is just a rotation. I think there is a rotation around an axis as seen from the second figure. However infinity thank you.